# Use webhook instead of infinity_polling()

Tags: python, webhooks, ngrok, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I am trying to add webhook into my code, following this template [PyTelegramBotApi webhook_aiohttp](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/webhook_examples/webhook_aiohttp_echo_bot.py).
My problem is that I cannot receive any updates from telegram using ngrok. What should be done in order to use webhook?

1. I use in terminal

> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8443

2. cd to the project's directory
3. Launch ngrok

> ngrok http 8443

Then output says that :

> ======== Running on http://localhost:8443 ======== (Press CTRL+C to quit)

My Project structure:

**database**

- database.py

**handlers**

- account.py
- buy.py
- join_group.py
- shipping_handlers.py
- start.py

**config.py**

**main.py**

```
from telebot import TeleBot
from membership_bot import config
from membership_bot.handlers.buy import buyHandlerTest, buyHandler
from membership_bot.handlers.join_group import joinGroupHandler
from membership_bot.handlers.start import startHandler, backHomeHandler
from membership_bot.handlers.shipping_handlers import checkout, got_payment
from membership_bot.handlers.account import accountHandler

bot = TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)

bot.register_message_handler(startHandler, commands=['start'], chat_types=['private'], pass_bot=True)
bot.register_callback_query_handler(joinGroupHandler, func=lambda message: message.data == "join_group", pass_bot=True)
bot.register_callback_query_handler(accountHandler, func=lambda message: message.data == "account", pass_bot=True)
bot.register_callback_query_handler(backHomeHandler, func=lambda message: message.data == "back_home", pass_bot=True)
bot.register_callback_query_handler(buyHandler, func=lambda message: message.data.startswith('Buy'), pass_bot=True)
bot.register_pre_checkout_query_handler(checkout, func=lambda query: True, pass_bot=True)
bot.register_message_handler(got_payment, content_types=['successful_payment'], pass_bot=True)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

My edited template with aiohttps:

```
import logging


from aiohttp import web

import telebot

API_TOKEN = 'MyToken'

WEBHOOK_HOST = '123.eu.ngrok.io'
WEBHOOK_PORT = 8443  # 443, 80, 88 or 8443 (port need to be 'open')
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = 'localhost'  

WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://{}:{}".format(WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/{}/".format(API_TOKEN)

logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

app = web.Application()


# Process webhook calls
async def handle(request):
    logging.info('Called handle requests........')
    if request.match_info.get('token') == bot.token:
        request_body_dict = await request.json()
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(request_body_dict)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return web.Response()
    else:
        return web.Response(status=403)


app.router.add_post('/{token}/', handle)


# Handle '/start' and '/help'
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    logging.info('Called start command........')
    bot.reply_to(message,
                 ("Hi there, I am EchoBot.\n"
                  "I am here to echo your kind words back to you."))


# Handle all other messages
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)


# Remove webhook, it fails sometimes the set if there is a previous webhook
logging.info('Removing webhook........')
bot.remove_webhook()
logging.info('Webhook removed........')
# Set webhook
logging.info('Setting webhook........')
bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH)
logging.info('Webhook set........')


# Start aiohttp server
web.run_app(
    app,
    host=WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
    port=WEBHOOK_PORT
    
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure proper functionality of your bot and avoid exposing 'http://localhost:8443' to '123.eu.ngrok.io', it's advisable to remove the port from `WEBHOOK_URL_BASE`. Here's the recommended adjustment:

```py
# To address the exposure issue from 'http://localhost:8443' to '123.eu.ngrok.io',
# it is recommended to eliminate the port from the 'WEBHOOK_URL_BASE' like so:

WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://{}".format(WEBHOOK_HOST)

# By making this change, your bot's webhook URL will be configured to use 'https',
```